# How to Extract and combine array from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have print_r result like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => A, B, C, D
    [1] => 15,20,24,19
)
```

how to make them like this :

```
Array
(
    [A] => 15
    [B] => 20
    [C] => 24
    [D] => 19
)
```

Great thanks for help :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php - Google could've told you that if you said "Hey Google, got results for combine arrays in php?" Even `array_merge` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [**explode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [**array_combine()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Assuming your initial array, `$arr`:

```
$new_arr = array_combine(explode(', ', $arr[0]), explode(',', $arr[1]));
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/eGWrEDpf)

Comment: Mark, how if the array is result of loop process, such result of for / while .. then [0] and [1] is automatically ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$b = array(15, 20, 24, 19);
$c = array();

foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    if (isset($b[$index])) {
        $c[$value] = $b[$index];
    }
}

var_dump($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is the way

```
<?php

$myArray = array(
    array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
    array(15, 20, 24, 19)
);

$combinedArray = array_combine($myArray[0], $myArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `explode()` your array index by comma and combine both array with keys and values using `array_combine()`

```
$a = explode(',',$arr[0]);
$b = explode(',',$arr[1]);
$new = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($new); //Array ( [A] => 15 [ B] => 20 [ C] => 24 [ D] => 19 )
```